# Perl change number to words

Tags: regex, numbers, normalization

Before this, I already had asked this same question and I got the answer, but I was mistaken. I need to convert numbers to words without using any library, especially Lingua::Numbers.

I found an example to separate digits in a phone number. Then I tried to implement the example in my script. But it didn't work.

Here is my script.

```
$x = "1104";
$x =~ s/1/ one /gi; #from 1-10, I, substitute number to words to words
$x =~ s/2/ two /gi;
$x =~ s/3/ three /gi;
$x =~ s/4/ four /gi;
$x =~ s/5/ five /gi;
$x =~ s/6/ six /gi;
$x =~ s/7/ seven /gi;
$x =~ s/8/ eight /gi;
$x =~ s/9/ nine /gi;
$x =~ s/10/ ten /gi;
$y = ($x{1}[thousand]?$x{1}[hundred and]?$x{2});  


    #then I will insert all my $x into $y.

$x =~ s/$x/$y/gi; #Here i substitute again to change all number to words

#that is my idea.

print "$x";
```

I tried to make it for 4 digits first. If it is successful, then I can proceed to insert until there are 7-8 digits or more.

Comment: Why don't you look up the implementation of the libraries and copy the parts that you need?

Comment: It does not seem like something that can be handled by regex (at least not easily). It would be much easier to do it in code. Also note 11-19 (e.g. eighteen) and (1-9)*10 (e.g. twenty or thirty) will also need to be made provision for separately.

Comment: Ok, technically just 11-13,15 and (1-3,5)*10 is different.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more intuitive to do this in code. Here is a start in C#, but should require minimal changes to work in almost any C-like language:

```
string Speak(int num)
{
    if (num < 0) return "negative " + Speak(-num);
    if (num >= 1000000000) return Speak(num / 1000000000) + " billion " + Speak(num % 1000000000);
    if (num >= 1000000) return Speak(num / 1000000) + " million " + Speak(num % 1000000);
    if (num >= 1000) return Speak(num / 1000) + " thousand " + Speak(num % 1000);
    if (num >= 100) return Speak(num / 100) + " hundred " + Speak(num % 100);
    if (num >= 20)
    {
        switch (num / 10)
        {
            case 2: return "twenty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 3: return "thirty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 4: return "forty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 5: return "fifty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 6: return "sixty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 7: return "seventy " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 8: return "eighty " + Speak(num % 10);
            case 9: return "ninety " + Speak(num % 10);
        }
    }
    switch (num)
    {
        case 0: return "";
        case 1: return "one";
        case 2: return "two";
        case 3: return "three";
        case 4: return "four";
        case 5: return "five";
        case 6: return "six";
        case 7: return "seven";
        case 8: return "eight";
        case 9: return "nine";
        case 10: return "ten";
        case 11: return "eleven";
        case 12: return "twelve";
        case 13: return "thirteen";
        case 14: return "fourteen";
        case 15: return "fifteen";
        case 16: return "sixteen";
        case 17: return "seventeen";
        case 18: return "eighteen";
        case 19: return "nineteen";
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Example:**

```
Speak("123000701") -> "one hundred twenty three million seven hundred one";
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to add support for zero, commas, and "and"-words.